# Which Where condition on Datetime will be faster?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a Datetime column called CreatedOn in a table. CreatedOn is also part of a non-clustered index where the order is descending.

Previously in the where condition I had a condition as follows

```
WHERE DateDiff(d,CreatedOn,GetDate()) < 180 AND ... other conditions
```

I changed this to

```
WHERE CreatedOn > '2012-04-04 00:00:00.000' AND ... other conditions
```

where I am calculating the cutoff date in C# code and then putting that in the adhoc query.

According to me, the second condition should be faster but I do not yet see a significant change in query execution times. But as the size of the table grows, which one will run faster?

Comment: The standard answers are: A) Do you think it'll really matter? And B) If so, test it with your data, table structure, indexes, server, etc. :-) (But I'd expect the second to be more optimizable, which might be faster.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: A it does (common SQL mistake). B no need because of A

Comment: @gbn: The answer to A is **not** necessarily that it matters. It depends on the data set (e.g., is the index important). Common mistake. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second form.

Putting functions on columns invalidates use of indexes (in almost all cases, so simply follow this rule always). See ["Ten Common SQL Programming Mistakes"](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/ten-common-sql-programming-mistakes/), number 2